# How to select fields using alias name?

Tags: postgresql

I have an select:

```
SELECT 
tb_dim_equipe.no_equipe "EQUIPE", 
tb_dim_profissional.no_profissional "PROFISSIONAL", 
no_cidadao "CIDADÃO", 
a.nu_cns "CNS", 
sum(case when co_dim_tempo >= 20190100 and co_dim_tempo <= 20200131 then 1 else 0 end) as "TOTAL" 
from (
SELECT no_cidadao, 
tb_fat_cad_individual.nu_cns, 
tb_fat_cad_individual.co_dim_profissional, 
tb_fat_cad_individual.co_dim_equipe from tb_fat_cidadao_pec 
join tb_fat_cad_individual on tb_fat_cad_individual.nu_cns = tb_fat_cidadao_pec.nu_cns 
join tb_fat_cidadao on tb_fat_cad_individual.co_seq_fat_cad_individual = tb_fat_cidadao.co_fat_cad_individual 
where st_mudou = 0 
and st_vivo = 1 
and st_gestante = 1 
and tb_fat_cidadao.co_dim_tempo_validade = 30001231) a 

left join (
SELECT tb_fat_atendimento_individual.nu_cns, 
tb_fat_atendimento_individual.co_dim_tempo 
from tb_fat_atendimento_individual 
join tb_dim_tempo on tb_dim_tempo.co_seq_dim_tempo = tb_fat_atendimento_individual.co_dim_tempo 
where co_seq_dim_tempo >= 20190100 
and co_seq_dim_tempo <= 20200131 
and ds_filtro_ciaps like '%ABP001%'

union SELECT tb_fat_proced_atend.nu_cns, 
tb_fat_proced_atend.co_dim_tempo 
from tb_fat_proced_atend 
join tb_dim_tempo on tb_dim_tempo.co_seq_dim_tempo = tb_fat_proced_atend.co_dim_tempo 
where co_seq_dim_tempo >= 20190100 
and co_seq_dim_tempo <= 20200131 
and ds_filtro_procedimento like '%0301010110%') b 
on a.nu_cns = b.nu_cns 
join tb_dim_equipe on tb_dim_equipe.co_seq_dim_equipe = a.co_dim_equipe 
join tb_dim_profissional on tb_dim_profissional.co_seq_dim_profissional = a.co_dim_profissional 
group by no_equipe, no_profissional, no_cidadao, a.nu_cns 
order by no_equipe, no_profissional, no_cidadao
```

This return to me five columns `EQUIPE, PROFISSIONAL, CIDADÃO, CNS and TOTAL`

I want to create a new select command like this:

```
SELECT sum(c.TOTAL) from *query above* c
```

but I receive the error that column not exists.

How I can use a select with the names of alias columns `EQUIPE, PROFISSIONAL, CIDADÃO, CNS and TOTAL`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like in the alias, you need to [quote the column identifier](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) if it is all-uppercase:

```
SELECT sum(c."TOTAL") from /*query above*/ c
--           ^     ^
```